# Adding timestamp to a log output

Tags: batch-file

This is my Windows script which is started every x minutes:

```
cd C:\
cd Speedtest
speedtest.exe -s 18571 -f csv>>Speedtest.log
```

How to add a timestamp to every log line?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59958082/edit) to include the exact output you currently receive inside `Speedtest.log` when using that command, and an example of how you want it to look. Your question is also off topic, your code is working as written and shows absolutely no indication that you've researched anything. We expect that you've attempted to code it yourself and failed, then posted your code for us to help you to fix. Also, you only need a single command above, not three, `"C:\Speedtest\speedtest.exe" -s 18571 -f csv>>"Speedtest.log"`.

Comment: `cd C:\ `and `cd Speedtest` should be combined to `cd /D C:\Speedtest` (if you insist on using `cd` at all)...

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume the application `speedtest` runs just one test run on each execution and outputs one or more lines without empty lines and on each line the current time on starting this application should be written first into the CSV file with `,` as list separator (default in most countries for CSV files). In this case the following batch file could be used for this task:

```
@cd /D "C:\Speedtest" 2>nul && @for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('speedtest.exe -s 18571 -f csv') do >>"Speedtest.log" @echo %TIME%,%%I
```

The first command **CD** changes the current directory to `C:\Speedtest`. This command fails if the directory does not exist. The error message output on changing directory failed is redirected with `2>nul` from handle **STDERR** (standard error) to device **NUL** to suppress it. There is nothing output by **CD** if the current directory could be successfully changed to the specified directory.

The operator `&&` results in executing the next command **FOR** only if **CD** exited with `0` indicating a successful change of the current directory which means the specified directory `C:\Speedtest` really exists.

**FOR** with option `/F` and a set specified between two `'` results in execution of one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the strings between the two `'` appended as further arguments. So executed is on Windows installed to `C:\Windows`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c speedtest.exe -s 18571 -f csv
```

The started Windows command process executes `speedtest.exe` with the four specified arguments and then closes itself because of option `/c`.

**FOR** captures all output written to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) and processes it after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** ignores all empty lines on processing the captured lines.

**FOR** would split up by default each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab separated string of a non-empty line to specified loop variable `I`. This string splitting behavior is not wanted here. For that reason option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters which disables line splitting behavior.

**FOR** would ignore by default all lines on which first substring starts with a semicolon because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line option. It is unknown if `speedtest` outputs the lines with a semicolon at beginning. For that reason the option `eol=` is used to define no end of line character which means all lines except empty lines are assigned completely to specified loop variable `I`.

The two options `delims=` and `eol=` are specified usually in a double quoted argument string to get the two equal signs and the space character between interpreted as literal characters and not as argument separators by Windows command processor. But `"delims= eol="` cannot be used here as **FOR** would interpret in this case `"` as end of line character. Therefore the two options must be written without `"` which requires escaping the two equal signs and the space character with `^` to be interpreted as literal character instead of argument separators by Windows command processor.

Windows command processor parses the entire line before execution of command **CD** and replaces during this parsing process `%TIME%` by the current value of the local time in format defined by the country configured for the account used to run this batch file. So the time written into the CSV file is the time on which the entire command line was parsed by `cmd.exe` before executing the command **CD** and on success next the other commands and executables.

The redirection operator `>>` with the file name `Speedtest.log` is specified left to command **ECHO** to be 100% safe that the line is written correct into the file without a trailing space even on ending with number `1` to `9`. It can be seen on running this batch file from within a command prompt window without the three `@` that `cmd.exe` moved `>>"Speedtest.log"` to end of the command line with inserting left to this string a space and `1` before executing command **CD**. It must be always taken into account how a command line looks like after processing it by Windows command processor before executing the command and not how it is written in the batch file.

**Note:** If the configured country is Germany, Austria, Switzerland, Luxembourg or Liechtenstein with time format `HH:mm:ss,ms` and list separator `;`, it is necessary to use a semicolon instead of a comma between `%TIME%` and `%%I` to produce a valid CSV file. `speedtest` outputs the data in this case hopefully also with `;` instead of `,`. Otherwise if `speedtest` outputs the data independent on list separator of the configured country always with a comma, it would be necessary to use on command **ECHO** either `"%TIME%",%%I` or `%TIME:,=.%,%%I` to get a valid [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) using comma as separator.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))